# What is valid input range for convolution neural network?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, normalization, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I uses CONV-maxpool-CONV-maxpool-CONV-maxpool-CONV-maxpool-hidden-logistic architecture for image detection application. 
Though most of examples normalize image intensity to [0,1] range.
But it seems not good because mean of input is not zero. that is not whitened input.
Is there any trial to use [-0.5,0.5] input range?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a lot of papers use Global Constrast Normalization, which consists of zero-centering the data and scaling so that your features have unit variance. This would make your image pixels lie in a symmetric about 0 interval like you said. For further "best practices" check out this article [Best Practices for Convolutional Neural Networks
Applied to Object Recognition in Images](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~adeandrade/assets/bpfcnnatorii.pdf).

Comment: I have tried after i upload questions. [-0.5,0.5] input trial was worse than [0,1] range trial.(hard to get optimized) But I don't know why.